# How to connect two tables with linked server

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I need to connect 2 tables from 2 different servers.

How can I do that in C#?

This is what I have so far:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (a,b,c,d) SELECT (a,b,c,d) FROM {1}", ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("main_table"), ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("main_table")), con);
```

`ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("main_table")` for both of them is the same.

```
 con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;
 con2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString
```

How to make this cmd to be workking with 2 different connection strings and with the same name for the table. Table name will change that's why it is saved in config.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution now?

Comment: I need to put in the command line query with 2 connection strings as I want to read from local database and insert into remote database. Both of them are the same with same column names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect 2 mysql tables with 2 connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854191/how-to-connect-2-mysql-tables-with-2-connection-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySQL` cannot dynamically link servers.

If you want a direct copy between the databases, you would need to create a `FEDERATED` table on the target server which would point to the source server, and just issue this command:

```
INSERT
INTO    main_table (a, b, c, d)
SELECT  a, b, c, d
FROM    federated_main_table
```

on the target server.

If you have multiple source servers and / or tables, you should create a federated table for each of them.

The other option would be selecting all data from the source server onto the client (into an array, persistent recordset etc.), then insert data cached on the client into the table on the target server.

Comment: Omg you got me confusec. Can you give me example on my connection stringa and cmd please

Comment: @denonth: no, I can't, it's impossible to do this with one command. You need two connection strings and two commands: `SELECT ... FROM source` and `INSERT ... INTO target ...`

Comment: Okay no problem so I need to have local federatet database and do select on it and then I insert what? Federated result into remote server

Comment: @denonth: there is a query in my post, you would just need to run it on the target server.

Comment: I want this to be done from C# when I need that. Can I save it as stored proc and call it? How do i merge two servers?

Comment: @denonth: yes, you can. By creating a federated table.

Comment: Ok I will try to do it that way